# Python creating list C = A + B so that changes to C affect A and B

Tags: python, reference

I am not sure if what I am asking is possible, but it would be convenient for a particular application if it were. I am building a trial list for an experiment, where a target can either match a prime exactly, or it can be a mismatch in a particular way that maintains a certain relationship to the target.  To be even more explicit, all of my stimuli fall into a 3 level taxonomy, of the form:

```
H = {
    'A1':{
        'B1':{
            'C1':[],'C2':[],'C3':[] },
        'B2':{
            'C1':[],'C2':[],'C3':[] },
        'B3':{
            'C1':[],'C2':[],'C3':[] }
    },
    'A2':{
        'B1':{
            'C1':[],'C2':[],'C3':[] },
        'B2':{
            'C1':[],'C2':[],'C3':[] },
        'B3':{
            'C1':[],'C2':[],'C3':[] }
    }
}
```

Where each list on the bottom the the "tree" is a particular set of stimuli.  If the prime and target match, that is simple.  If they do not, I want to draw randomly, without replacement, from a different C group under the same B group.

My intended solution was to leverage how (I thought) python handles references and make a temporary list that I could pop() a stimuli from. So, if the trial is incongruent, and the prime is from H[A1][B1][C1], I want to pop() from a list:

```
tempList = H[A1][B1][C2] + H[A1][B1][C3]
```

However, presumably because I am appending the two lists, the reference to the lists in the dictionaries is broken, so if I remove an idem from the temp list, it is not reflected in the dictionaries.  Is there a way to maintain the reference?  Thank you!

EDIT:
This toy example does not work as expected:

```
>>> d = {'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]}
>>> l = d['A'] + d['B']
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> l.pop(2)
3
>>> l
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
>>> d
{'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a new class that takes `H` and the paths to the sublists in the initializer, and override [`__*item__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) such that the underlying lists will be affected instead.

**EDIT:**

A partial example:

```
class listxer(object):
  def __init__(self, structure, paths):
    self.structure = structure
    self.paths = paths

  def _descend(self, path):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x[y], path, self.structure)

  def __len__(self):
    return sum(len(self._descend(path)) for path in self.paths)

  def __getitem__(self, item):
    if item < 0:
      raise ValueError('negative indices not supported!')
    for path in self.paths:
      cur = self._descend(path)
      if item > len(cur):
        item -= len(cur)
        continue
      else:
        return cur[item]
    else:
      raise IndexError('list index out of range')

H = [[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]]

mystruct = listxer(H, ((0, 0), (0, 1)))
print len(mystruct)
print mystruct[3]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply/solution.  I think I need an example to work from to actually build the class properly, though.  Sorry, I have much to learn.

Comment: @Ignacio: please provide a short example, i too would very much appreciate that.

Comment: Thank you for the example! I'll have to spend some time with it.

Answer (score 1):

Though it would be difficult for me to give a specialized solution but I will try to give you the answer to your underline question

Given two list, A & B, how to generate a List C such that

if C = A + B

changing C would eventually change either A or B.

Take the following example

I create two lists A & B which are themselves lists of numbers.

```
>>> A=[[i] for i in range(0,10)]
>>> B=[[i] for i in range(10,20)]
```

I then add them up.

```
>>> C=A+B
```

Now if I change any element of `C` it would either change `A` or `B`

```
>>> C[1][0]=-1
>>> C
[[0], [-1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19]]
>>> A
[[0], [-1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
>>> C[11][0]=-1
>>> C
[[0], [-1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [-1], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19]]
>>> B
[[10], [-1], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19]]
>>>
```

Comment: Oh, I see the key difference.  You create a list of lists out of the two original lists.  This maintains the references correctly. This might work well, but it's not as clean as I might like.  I am still interested in building a new class as suggested by @Ignacio